# grep specific pattern from a log file

Tags: grep

I am passing all my svn commit log messages to a file and want to grep only the JIRA issue numbers from that. 
Some lines might have more than 1 issue number, but I want to grab only the first occurrence.

The pattern is XXXX-999 (number of alpha and numeric char is not constant) 
Also, I don't want the entire line to be displayed, just the JIRA number, without duplicates. I use the following command but it didn't work.

Could someone help please?

```
 cat /tmp/jira.txt | grep '^[A-Z]+[-]+[0-9]'
```

Log file sample

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 r62086 | userx | 2015-05-12 11:12:52 -0600 (Tue, 12 May 2015) | 1 line
 Changed paths:
   M /projects/trunk/gradle.properties
 ABC-1000  This is a sample commit message    
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 r62084 | usery | 2015-05-12 11:12:12 -0600 (Tue, 12 May 2015) | 1 line
 Changed paths:
   M /projects/training/package.jar
 EFG-1001  Test commit
```

Output expected:

```
ABC-1000
EFG-1001
```

Comment: can you give an example or two of a line you are trying to match?

Comment: I have edited the query. Its looks better that way than a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it seems like you have the second `+` in the wrong place, it should be at the end of `[0-9]` expression.

Second, I think all you need to do this is use the `-o` option to grep (to display only the matching portion of the line), then pipe the `grep` output through `sort -u`, like this:

`cat /tmp/jira.txt | grep -oE '^[A-Z]+-[0-9]+' | sort -u`

Although if it were me, I'd skip the `cat` step and just give the filename to `grep`, as so:

`grep -oE '^[A-Z]+-[0-9]+' /tmp/jira.txt | sort -u`

Six of one, half a dozen of the other, really.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But, this command returns nothing. I tried both.

Comment: @VRK I forgot that on many versions of `grep`, you need the `-E` option for `+` to gain its special meaning. Answer edited, try the new commands.

Comment: Awesome. Both commands work good. Thank you for the commands and explaining it so well.